# Identify this 10 Column Solitaire

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

A few days ago the person next to me on the plane was playing a solitaire game I had never seen, and I have been looking for the game name without success.

What I could figure out is:

**Deal**:

- Two decks (104 cards).
- 10 columns, each with 5 face-down cards.

**Movements**:

- The Draw action: draw from the deck a single card on ALL 10 columns (10 cards in total).
- The Move action: you can move partial cards as usual between columns.
- When no arrangement is possible, you draw the deck again.

**Special rules:**

- You can combine same suit and when you have A-K sequence, that set goes away.

**End game:**

- Win: completes all 8 sequence of A-K.
- Lose: getting stuck and run out of cards in the deck.

### **Update**: It looks like some kind of a Spider game.

Comment: By "blocked", you mean face-down?

Comment: By "naipe" you mean card?  in order to combine the two cards, they must be identical in both Suit and Rank?

Comment: @Cohensius I mean they cant be accessed b/c there are other cards on "top", but they are indeed face down

Comment: It sounds exactly like "Spider Solitaire" included in the games supplied with Windows 7. However, the initial deal is uneven: the first 4 columns are dealt with 6 cards, so there are 54 cards in the deal, leaving 50 cards in the deck – 5 whole rows of 10 cards. It can be played with 1 suit (easy), 2 suits or 4 suits (hard), but always with 104 cards. The next row cannot be dealt if there are any empty columns on the table.